# How to use the value returned from a method

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Movies {
   static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   static String movies[] = {"1. IT\tP200", "2. The Battleship Island\tP300", "3. Annabelle Creation\tP180", "4. Woke Up Like This\t100"};
   static String name;
   static int seats=0;
   static int number=0;
    public static void getName(){
        System.out.print("Please enter your Name: ");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to MOVIEWORLD, " +name);
        getMovieTitle();

    }

public static int getMovieTitle(){

    System.out.println("\nNOW SHOWING");
   for (String movie : movies) {
       System.out.println(movie);
   }
   char choice;
   System.out.print("Would you like to get a ticket? (Y/N)");
   choice= scan.next().charAt(0);
    switch(choice){
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            System.out.print("Please select a movie: ");
            number = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You have Selected "+movies[number-1].substring(3,movies[number-1].length()));
            getSeats();
            break;


        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            System.out.println("Thank you!");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            getMovieTitle();
            break;
    }
    return number;
}

public static int getSeats(){
    System.out.print("How many seats would you like? ");
    int seat = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("Reserved # of seats is %d ",seat );
    return seat;
}



public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("\tMOVIEWORLD");
    System.out.println("________________________");
    getName();

    int mynum;
    mynum=getMovieTitle();
    int mynum2;
    mynum2=getSeats();
     int mov1 = 200;
     int mov2 = 300;
     int mov3 = 180;
     int mov4 = 100;
     int cost;
     int money;
     int change;
     char c;
     System.out.print("Print Receipt?(y/n)");
     c= scan.next().charAt(0);
     switch(c){
         case 'y':
         case 'Y':
     if(mynum == 1){
         cost=mov1*mynum2;
         System.out.print("Total: Php"+cost);
         System.out.print("Received cash is: Php");
         money=scan.nextInt();
         change=money-cost;
         System.out.print("Your change is: Php"+change);

     }
     else if(mynum == 2){
         cost=mov2*mynum2;
         System.out.print("Total: Php"+cost);
         System.out.print("Received cash is: Php");
         money=scan.nextInt();
         change=money-cost;
         System.out.print("Your change is: Php"+change);
     }
     else if(mynum == 3){
         cost=mov3*mynum2;
         System.out.print("Total: Php"+cost);
         System.out.print("Received cash is: Php");
         money=scan.nextInt();
         change=money-cost;
         System.out.print("Your change is: Php"+change);
     }
     else if(mynum == 4){
         cost=mov4*mynum2;
         System.out.print("Total: Php"+cost);
         System.out.print("Received cash is: Php");
         money=scan.nextInt();
         change=money-cost;
         System.out.print("Your change is: Php"+change);
     }
     break;
         case 'n':
         case 'N':
             System.out.println("Thank you");
             break;

         default:
              System.out.println("Thank you");
              System.exit(0);

}
}
}
```

I am trying to get the cost, the money received , and the change.  But I am having a trouble in using the returned values in my methods. After selecting how many seats i wanted the program just exits.

This is the values that i would like to use in my main method. First is the number

```
 System.out.print("Please select a movie: ");
            number = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You have Selected "+movies[number-1].substring(3,movies[number-1].length()));
            getSeats();


        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            System.out.println("Thank you!");
            System.exit(0);
        default:
            getMovieTitle();

    }
    return number;
```

Second is the seats so i can multiply it with the number.

```
 public static int getSeats(){
    System.out.print("How many seats would you like? ");
    int seats = scan.nextInt();

    return seats;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `return number` does? It returns `number`. You have to store that returned value into a variable in the code where you call the function, at which point you have the value to use. Find a tutorial.

Comment: You need a `break;` at the end of each case in your `switch` statement, otherwise you execute not only the selected case but every following case as well.

Comment: int mynum;
mynum=getMovieTitle();

is this correct? in returning the value of _number_ in the method getMovieTitle?
@KenWhite

Comment: Yes I have already added the break. Thank you for that. Now my problem is that it kept on looping at getSeats();
@KevinAnderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need a `break`:

   ```
   case 'Y':
       System.out.print("Please select a movie: ");
       number = scan.nextInt();
       System.out.println("You have Selected "+movies[number-
           1].substring(3,movies[number-1].length()));
       getSeats();
       break;
   ```
2. You need to assign the number of seats to the global `seats` variable that you created in the beginning of the program, rather than a local variable.:

   ```
   public static int getSeats(){
    System.out.print("How many seats would you like? ");
    seats = scan.nextInt();

    return seats;
   }
   ```

Update:

3. In your updated question, you're capturing the returned values of `getMovieTitle()` and `getSeats()` with `mynum` and `mynum2` in the main method, but still calling those methods inside `getName()` and `getMovieTitle()` respectively. Just comment those calls:

   ```
   public static void getName(){
      System.out.print("Please enter your Name: ");
      name = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("\nWelcome to MOVIEWORLD, " +name);
      //getMovieTitle();

   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   case 'Y':
       System.out.print("Please select a movie: ");
       number = scan.nextInt();
       System.out.println("You have Selected "+movies[number-1].substring(3,movies[number-1].length()));
       //getSeats();
       break;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for that. But now I kept on looping on the getSeats() method. It wont get to this part which I added.
`int mynum;
        mynum=getMovieTitle();
        int mynum2;
        mynum2=getSeats();
         int mov1 = 200;
         int mov2 = 300;
         int mov3 = 180;
         int mov4 = 100;
         int cost;
         int money;
         int change;
         char c;
         System.out.print("Print Receipt?(y/n)");
         c= scan.next().charAt(0);
         switch(c){
break;
}`

Comment: Could you update your question to show where exactly you added that?

Comment: I added a switch statement after calling the getName() method. But it gets stuck at the getSeats().

*updated my question alreay

Comment: Answer updated. You were calling those methods more than once despite already getting the values

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! Now its running good. I thought I was just assigning the returned value but instead I was calling it already.

Comment: You're welcome :) Could you help me out as well by accepting the answer? It gives both of us reputation points, and tells any future readers of this question that this answer is the correct solution.

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm new to this site. The check button right?

Comment: I noticed you were new :) No worries, it's entirely optional. Yep, the check button. Thanks! :) see you